# Non zero partial derivatives in implicit function theorem?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, implicit-function-theorem

Simple proofs of this in 3 dimensions $z(x,y)$ impose a $dz = 0$ constraint to solve for $dy/dx$.  This implies $z(x, y) = \text{constant}$.  Why are the partial derivatives in general in the theorem non zero if $z = \text{constant}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point is that the equation $z(x,y)=c$ holds only for some $y$ (dependent on $x$). For example, the equation $x^2+y^2=1$ holds for some $(x,y)$ and not others.  The partial derivatives of the function $z(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ are not zero.

Then we consider $y(x)$, a function defined implicitly by the equation $z(x,y)=c$. It's true that $z(x,y(x))=c$ for all $x$. So, when we differentiate this **composition** with respect to $x$, the result  is zero.

In the above example, $\frac{d}{dx}(x^2+y(x)^2 )=0$ if $y(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$. This does not contradict the fact that $x^2+y^2$ has nonzero partials.

Comment: I agree that $x^2+y^2$ has nonzero partials however when it is equal to c it should have zero partials since it's a constant

Comment: As I said, it's equal to $c$ in *some* places. For example, $x^2+y^2=25$ holds on a circle of radius $5$, and only there. Take a point on this circle, like $(3,4)$. The function $z(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ has partials $z_x=2x$ and $z_y=2y$, so at the point $(3,4)$ we have $z_x=6$ and $z_y=8$. Not zero. Does this contradict the fact that $z$ is constant on the circle? Not at all. The partial derivatives measure the rate of change in horizontal and vertical directions. By following these directions from the point $(3,4)$, we leave the circle, and get different values of $z$.

Comment: So I cannot replace z with c in a partial derivative because it's a constant? Dz/dx != Dc/dx

Comment: Correct, you cannot. It's the same for functions of one variable, actually. Take $f(t)=t^2$: we have $f(3)=9$, but the derivative $f'(3)$ is not the same as the derivative of $9$, which would be zero.

Comment: Very clear! The only difference is that we made restriction on $y$ ($y = y(x)$) now.